# to perform addition operation on forloop.counter in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to perform reduce the value of forloop.counter in django template for the given condition, is it possible in django.

Below is demonstrated the example

```
{% for i in item %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %}
        Start
    {% endif %}
        {% if i %}
            item{{ forloop.counter }}
        {% else %}
            ######### Here I want to reduce value of forloop.counter by 1 ###########
        {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
        End
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

In above code for 8 perfect item output will be

```
Start
item1
item2
item3
item4
End
Start
item5
item6
item7
item8
End
```

but suppose item2 is None, then output is

```
Start
item1 
item3
item4
End
Start
item5
item6
item7
item8
End
```

I want to print it in form of proper ascending order (incremented by 1 at each step) by reducing value of forloop each time if condition is not satisfied. Please don't suggest about the custom template tag, I know that and I consider it as last option.

Comment: Have you tried by `add` filter by having parameter `-1`?

Comment: will forloop.counter value decrement by -1 using add:-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really doubt django will let you mess with `forloop.counter` that easily, and wouldn't mess with it anyway. The obvious solution would be to filter out your list before you iterate over it, which can be done in your view or (if you insist on doing it in the template) using a custom filter.

Or you can wrap your list in a generator function that will take care of filtering and numbering, ie:

```
def filteriternum(seq):
    num = 0
    for item in seq:
        if not item:
            continue
        num += 1
        yield num, item
```

Here again, you can either do the wrapping in your view or write a custom template filter of tag that will do the wrapping.

Comment: I thought of doing it in that way, but iterating a long list makes two iteration whether I do it in view or in template using filter

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Then wrap your list in a filtering (or renumbering) generator

Comment: even though it is not 100% what i want, bt i feel among all it is most appropriate answer. Thanks @bruno :)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh thanks for accepting my answer. Could you elaborate on why it doesn't "100%" fit your needs ? I may have misunderstood or overlooked something in your question but I just don't see what exactly...

Comment: no your answer is perfect, but i thought there will be some process in django for decrementing forloop.counter value, but i think there is no such safe process, so your answer seems right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
{% for i in item %}
    {% cycle 'Start' '' '' '' %}
    {% if i %}
            item{{ forloop.counter }}
    {% else %}
            empty item{{ forloop.counter }}
    {% endif %}
    {% cycle '' '' '' 'End' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the output:

```
Start
item1 
empty item2 
item3
item4
End 
Start
item5 
item6 
item7 
item8
End
```

---

**UPDATE**: I've found something really funny, how to actually decrement the forloop.counter using a 'local' variable:

```
{% cycle 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 as dec %}

{% for i in item %}
    {% cycle 'Start' '' '' '' %}
    {% if i %}
        item{{ forloop.counter|add:dec }}
    {% else %}
        <!-- empty {% cycle dec %} here we move to the next decrementing value -->
    {% endif %}
    {% cycle '' '' '' 'End' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand how exactly cycle is working here and you are not getting 2 again which is a problem

Comment: What is the desired output? I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. I've updated the answer - check it now.

Comment: no @Tisho, see the updated question, it says number should increment by 1. Now you got my point.

Comment: You need a second independent counter then... Or to remove the None-values from the list before passing them to the template. Or to use a custom tag... I've found a funny way to actually decrement the forloop.counter, but it will work for a limited items though :)

Comment: ok, finally instead of playing with forloop.counter, i adopted technique @brunodesthuilliers told me. i think that is the only way. You also post your solution, may be that works for me too :)

Comment: Yep, the solution of @brunodesthuilliers is fine. No way to achieve it using standard django tags. The last code I've posted works for only 10 missing items in the list ;) After that it will roll the decrementing value from 0 :) But it was funny how you can use a `cycle` iterator in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from Tisho's answer:

```
{% for i in item %}
    {% if i %}
        {% cycle 'Start' '' '' '' %}
            item{% cycle 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 %}
        {% cycle '' '' '' 'End' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That would output:

```
Start
item1 
item2
item3 
item4 
End 
Start
item5
item6 
item7 
item8 
End
```

so no holes any longer ! But this only works if you have a limited number of values, as you're obliged to write them all in the 2nd `cycle` tag used...

Answer (score -2):

if django template can't fulfill, try write one youself, check here [django custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: i want to know whether is it possible in django, of course that is last option for me.

Comment: Please see the question again.. !